# Rebase on the root and keep empty commits

Tags: git

Suppose I have a branch that consists of three commits, one of them empty:

```
# On branch test
3208910 empty
85c949c bar
0c1a615 foo
```

I want to rebase it on the root and from the man page it seems that `--root --keep-empty` is exactly what I need.

However, both `git rebase -i --root` and `git rebase -i --root --keep-empty` omit the empty commit and show me this plan instead:

```
pick 0c1a615 foo
pick 85c949c bar
```

How can I rebase the entire branch and keep empty commits at the same time?

P.S. I needed this to remove a few first commits on the branch and I managed to achieve that with `filter-branch` as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149520/git-remove-root-commit/6149972#6149972), but I'm still interested in knowing if `rebase` is capable of that. Is it a bug in Git that I found? It's hard to believe this behavior is intentional but I'm not sure.

P.P.S. I found that I can edit the plan by hand and add `pick 3208910`.

Comment: I don't really know why. But it has to do with the `--root` flag you are using. Doing the same on a branch - `git rebase -i --keep-empty master` seems to work as expected.

Comment: `git rebase -i --root --keep-empty --preserve-merges` also works for some reason. The `--root` option is really weird, I don’t get what’s happening there…

Comment: @poke: probably just a bug ... `--root` internally works by setting the "onto" target to the empty tree, which is not a commit but works for cherry-pick.  It's not immediately obvious what, but without the preserve merge setting, something's removing the pick command for the empty-diff commit, perhaps because the difference itself is an empty tree and hence matches $onto.

Comment: you could `git cherry-pick` the empty commit to the root branch

Comment: Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) should improve and resolve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50122618/6309

Answer (score 1):

It is connected with the two modes of `git rebase`.

**Patch-id** approach should keep the empty commit and is the default behaviour.

However, as correctly pinpointed, `--root` flag is a shortcut for "onto NULL" and this triggers the **fork-point** mode.

More information can be deducted from:

- [Why is git rebase discarding my commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22790765)
- [Why is "rebase --onto ABC" different than "rebase ABC"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42616979)

Answer (score 0):

> `--root` flag is a shortcut for "`onto NULL`" and this triggers the fork-point mode.

This is no longer the case with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), since the incompatible options "`--root`" and "`--fork-point`" of "`git rebase`" have been marked and documented as being incompatible.

See [commit a35413c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a35413c3785bf71e2c018691d6cd5f93638ba9ae) (27 Apr 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6d6b412](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d6b412da32229bf6a5f366a72b5ad29cc70ce59), 01 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a35413c3785bf71e2c018691d6cd5f93638ba9ae): display an error if `--root` and `--fork-point` are both provided
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Alexander Berg</sup>
> <sup>Documentation-by: Alban Gruin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
>
> - `--root` implies we want to rebase all commits since the beginning of history.
> - `--fork-point` means we want to use the reflog of the specified upstream to find the best common ancestor between `<upstream>` and `<branch>` and only rebase commits since that common ancestor.
>
> These options are clearly contradictory, so throw an error (instead of segfaulting on a `NULL` pointer) if both are specified.

[The error will be](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a35413c3785bf71e2c018691d6cd5f93638ba9ae/builtin/rebase.c#L1655-L1656):

> ```
> cannot combine '--root' with '--fork-point'
> ```

Comment: I think OP's problem is that rebase strips previous cherrypicks, and its implementation of the `--root` commit puts an empty commit at the base, so when it checks patch id's the new empty commit looks like it's already been applied.

Comment: @jthill Agreed. This was more to mention this corner case when using `git rebase --root`.