# Why is "rebase --onto ABC" different than "rebase ABC"?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Using git 2.11, [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) documentation says:

> The current branch is reset to <upstream>, or <newbase> if the --onto
>   option was supplied. This has the exact same effect as git reset
>   --hard  (or ). ORIG_HEAD is set to point at the tip of the branch before the reset.

I understand it as if `upstream` and `newbase` points to the same "base reference", then this means the two rebase syntaxes below are equivalent:

```
git rebase ABC
git rebase --onto ABC
```

Here is the demo I setup. Let's assume the current branch is `FeatureABC` it is perfectly in sync with the remote branch.

```
#---create two identical branches, behind current branch by 5 commits
(FeatureABC) git branch Demo1-Rebase-ABC      HEAD~4
(FeatureABC) git branch Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC HEAD~4

#---Make a new commit in branch Demo1
git checkout Demo1-Rebase-ABC
echo "Demo of: git rebase FeatureABC Demo1-Rebase-ABC" > ./Demo1_BogusFile.txt
git add ./Demo1_BogusFile.txt
git commit -m "Create file Demo1_BogusFile.txt"

git rebase FeatureABC
```

> First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it
>   ... Applying: Create file Demo1_BogusFile.txt

`git log --oneline -3` shows that the branch `Demo1-Rebase-ABC` is sync'ed with the HEAD of FeatureABC. And the commit "Create file Demo1_BogusFile.txt" was correctly applied on top of it.

```
#---Make a new commit in branch Demo2
git checkout Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC
echo "Demo of: git rebase --onto FeatureABC Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC" > ./Demo2_Onto_BogusFile.txt
git add ./Demo2_Onto_BogusFile.txt
git commit -m "Create file Demo2_Onto_BogusFile.txt"

git rebase --onto FeatureABC
```

> There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please
>   specify which branch you want to rebase against. See git-rebase(1) for
>   details.
>
> ```
> git rebase <branch>
> ```
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so
>   with:
>
> ```
> git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC
> ```

I misunderstood the warning message. Thinking that git was confused in the defaults when --onto is used. So I just want to "help" by telling git the current branch I want to rebase

```
git rebase --onto FeatureABC Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC
```

> First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...

`git log --oneline -3` shows that the branch `Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC` becomes **identical** than `FeatureABC`. The last commit "Create file Demo2_Onto_BogusFile.txt" has vanished and the file `./Demo2_Onto_BogusFile.txt` is deleted.

**Question**: what is the reason the `git rebase --onto FeatureABC Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC` didn't apply the new commits made on the `Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC` branch?

Comment: What is in the branch.<name>.remote and branch.<name>.merge options for your Demo branches?

Comment: @oyvind Can you please show me the git command to run to get these infos?

Comment: `git config --get branch.Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC.merge`

Comment: `git config --get branch.Demo1-Rebase-ABC.merge`

Comment: `git config --get branch.Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC.remote`

Comment: `git config --get branch.Demo1-Rebase-ABC.remote`

Comment: Sorry about the separate comments, I don't know how to get a newline on mobile.

Comment: Oh like `git config --local --get-regexp branch.Demo.+` ? OK will do that when I get home. BTW, I think it is not possible to force a newline in Stackoverflow's comment.

Comment: Well, I mean exactly as I wrote them. --get-regexp will return keys, not values, and I want the values.

Comment: The 4 statements `git config --get branch.xxx` return nothing. I suppose b/c these 2 Demo branches don't track any remote branch. After reading carefully the answer of @torek I have understood the mistake I made. See my comment under his answer below. BTW `git config --local --get-regexp branch.Demo.+` is exactly equivalent to the 4 cmds you showed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same, and this can get complicated by the `--fork-point` option as well.  I think this may be what bit you, although it's not possible to be sure, just from what you have described, as one of the steps you outlined merely produces an error.

#### I start with a reasonable guess, but it *is* a guess

To see what's really happening it is very helpful to draw (part of) the commit graph, with special attention to labeling since you are using multiple names that all point to a single commit.

> Let's assume the current branch is `FeatureABC` it is perfectly in sync with the remote branch.

Hence we have something like this—but *something like* is not really good enough; *you* have the repository, so *you* should draw the graph; I have to *guess:*

```
...--o--A--B--C--D--E   <-- FeatureABC (HEAD), origin/FeatureABC
```

Now you run:

> ```
> #---create two identical branches, behind current branch by 5 commits
> (FeatureABC) git branch Demo1-Rebase-ABC      HEAD~4
> (FeatureABC) git branch Demo2-Rebase-onto-ABC HEAD~4
> ```

Since `HEAD~4` names commit `A` (`HEAD~1` is `D`, `HEAD~2` is `C`, and so on), we need to do something to mark the fact that these two new names point to commit `A`.  I'm going to shorten the names to just `Demo1` and `Demo2` though.  (I've created a repository with only commits `o` through `E` at this point, and actually run `git branch Demo1 HEAD~4; git branch Demo2 HEAD~4` here.)

```
...--o--A              <-- Demo1, Demo2
         \
          B--C--D--E   <-- FeatureABC (HEAD), origin/FeatureABC
```

Incidentally, `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` ("get help from A DOG" as someone put it) shows this test repository this way (there is no `origin/` branch in my case):

```
* c4a0671 (HEAD -> master) E
* a7b8ae4 D
* 3deea72 C
* b11828d B
* ffc29b5 (Demo2, Demo1) A
* 3309a8d initial
```

Next, you check out Demo1, moving `HEAD`:

> ```
> git checkout Demo1-Rebase-ABC
> ```

```
...--o--A              <-- Demo1 (HEAD), Demo2
         \
          B--C--D--E   <-- FeatureABC, origin/FeatureABC
```

and modify the work-tree, add the modified file to the index, and commit, to make a new commit which I will call `F`, which updates the `HEAD` branch and therefore separates `Demo1` and `Demo2`.  I'll now use my own commands and their output here:

```
$ git checkout Demo1
Switched to branch 'Demo1'
$ echo demo1 > demo1.txt && git add demo1.txt && git commit -m F
[Demo1 89773b6] F
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 demo1.txt
```

Drawing the graph gets a bit harder; I'll use a row up:

```
          F            <-- Demo1 (HEAD)
         /
...--o--A              <-- Demo2
         \
          B--C--D--E   <-- FeatureABC, origin/FeatureABC
```

Now we get to your first `git rebase` command.  I have to use `master`, of course:

```
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: F
```

This works on the current branch (`HEAD` or `Demo1`).  It finds commits that are on `HEAD` that are not on `FeatureABC` (`FeatureABC..` in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) syntax).  That's commit `F`.  These commits get put into a list of commits to *maybe* copy—`git rebase` will check for commits with the same `git patch-id` and skip them, although clearly that did not happen here.  So now commit `F` is copied to new commit `F'`, with different hash ID and different base:

```
          F              [abandoned]
         /
...--o--A                <-- Demo2
         \
          B--C--D--E     <-- FeatureABC, origin/FeatureABC
                    \
                     F'  <-- Demo1 (HEAD)
```

(Here's the actual `git log` output, showing the new commit hash for the copy.  The original, now-abandoned `F` is not shown unless I add `Demo1@{1}` to the command, which I did here.  The original is the *second* `F` shown, i.e., the earlier commit:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph Demo1@{1}
* c1d0896 (HEAD -> Demo1) F
* c4a0671 (master) E
* a7b8ae4 D
* 3deea72 C
* b11828d B
| * 89773b6 F
|/  
* ffc29b5 (Demo2) A
* 3309a8d initial
```

I like the horizontal graph better, but this one has more information, specifically the abbreviated hash IDs.)

#### Reproducer fails, and I'll have to guess again

Now we try to repeat this with `Demo2`, but it fails.  Here are my actual commands, cut-and-pasted.  The first step works fine:

```
$ git checkout Demo2
Switched to branch 'Demo2'
$ echo demo2 > demo2.txt && git add demo2.txt && git commit -m G
[Demo2 ae30665] G
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 demo2.txt
```

No longer drawing the original `F`, here is the new graph.  I put `G` where `F` used to be, although I could draw this as just `...--o--A--G`:

```
          G              <-- Demo2 (HEAD)
         /
...--o--A
         \
          B--C--D--E     <-- FeatureABC, origin/FeatureABC
                    \
                     F   <-- Demo1
```

The rebase, however, does not work.  Again I have to use `master` instead of `FeatureABC`, but this would behave the same way in your example, given that the `git branch` command did not set an upstream ("tracking") name:

```
$ git rebase --onto master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details.

    git rebase <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> Demo2
```

The reason `git rebase` failed with this error message is that [`--onto` has absorbed the argument as `<newtarget>`, leaving us with no `<upstream>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html):

> If `<upstream>` is not specified, the upstream configured in `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` options will be used (see [git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for details) **and the `--fork-point` option is assumed**. If you are currently not on any branch or if the current branch does not have a configured upstream, the rebase will abort.

The boldface here is mine, but it's also, I think, the key.  I assume you ran a `git rebase --onto <somename>` that *did not* fail.  For it to have not-failed, your branch must have had an upstream set.  That upstream probably *was* `origin/FeatureABC` or similar, and that meant that as far as Git was concerned, you were running:

```
git rebase --onto FeatureABC --fork-point origin/FeatureABC
```

and *not*:

```
git rebase --onto FeatureABC --no-fork-point origin/FeatureABC
```

Some [further reading in the (overly cryptic, in my opinion) `git rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) will turn up this sentence:

> If either `<upstream>` or `--root` is given on the command line, then
>    the default is `--no-fork-point`, otherwise the default is
>    `--fork-point`.

In other words:

```
git rebase FeatureABC
```

*turns off* the `--fork-point` option, as does:

```
git rebase --onto FeatureABC FeatureABC
```

but:

```
git rebase
```

or:

```
git rebase --onto FeatureABC
```

leaves the `--fork-point` option *on*.

#### What `--fork-point` is about

The *goal* of `--fork-point` is to specifically *drop* commits that used to be, at one time, in your upstream, but are no longer in your upstream.  See [Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486141/1256452) for an example.  [The specific mechanism is complicated and relies on the upstream branch's reflog.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42546368/1256452)  Since I don't have either your repository or your reflog, I cannot test out your specific case—but that's one reason, and probably the most likely reason given the hints in your question, that a commit that *would* affect the rebase *tree result* would get dropped.  The commits that are dropped due to having the same [patch ID](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html) as an upstream commit are ones that [**edit**:] often<sup>1</sup> will *not* affect the final tree of the last-copied commit: they would just cause merge conflicts and/or force you to use `git rebase --skip` to skip over them, if they were included.

---

<sup>1</sup>It occurred to me after writing this that there is an important exception (which probably has nothing to do with the original question, but which I should mention).  Rebasing a feature or topic branch onto a more mainline branch, when a commit was first cherry-picked *out* of the feature into the mainline, and then *reverted* in the mainline, will cause a problem.  Consider, e.g.:

```
...--o--*--P--Q--C'-R--S--X--T   <-- mainline
         \
          A--B--C--D--E          <-- topic
```

where `C'` is a copy of commit `C`, and `X` is a revert of commit `C` that should not have been put into `mainline` yet.  Doing:

```
git checkout topic
git rebase mainline
```

will instruct Git to put commits `A` through `E` into the "candidates to copy" list, but also look at `P` through `T` to see if any were already adopted.  Commit `C` *was* adopted, as `C'`.  If `C` and `C'` have the same patch ID—usually, they *will*—Git will drop `C` from the list as "already copied".  However, `C` was explicitly *reverted* in commit `X`.

Whoever does the rebase needs to notice, and carefully restore `C` if it is required and appropriate.

This particular behavior is *not* a problem with `git merge` (since merge ignores intermediate commits), only with `git rebase`.

Comment: "I assume you ran a `git rebase --onto <somename>` that did not fail". Oh this ... and I thought it was a negligible detail, oups. Indeed, I got the same error "There is no tracking information for the current branch". So I ran `git rebase --onto FeatureABC Demo2`. The error disappeared. Not sure why as I though rebase knows how to operate on the current branch by default. I made obviously a bad cmd b/c the effects was that it wiped out clean the new commit made in Demo2 and irremediably deleted the Demo2.txt file too.

Comment: Reran my test and could reproduced the error you described when doing `git rebase --onto master` (There is no tracking information for the current branch). In fact, I did `git rebase --onto FeatureABC Demo2` initially when I asked the question. I didn't realize that this makes a big difference. What was te most puzzling is the deletion of the latest commit in Demo2 branch. And `--fork-point` is indeed the reason. After reading your answer [Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486141/git-rebase-commit-select-in-fork-point-mode). I see why now.