# Empty commits removed after interactive rebase, even though --keep-empty is used

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have some trouble using the `--keep-empty` option of `git rebase`, and I'm
not sure whether I'm misunderstanding what this option does, or there's a bug.

Here is a minimal example:

#### Setup

1. Create a new Git repository and an initial, unrelated commit.

   ```
   $ git init
   $ echo something >base.txt
   $ git add base.txt
   $ git commit -m 'some base commit to not run into the root corner case'
   ```
2. Create a new commit which adds two new files.

   ```
   $ echo A >a.txt; echo B >b.txt
   $ git add a.txt b.txt
   $ git commit -m 'add A and B'
   ```
3. Modify one of the files.

   ```
   $ echo A1 >a.txt
   $ git add a.txt
   $ git commit -m 'change A'
   ```
4. Modify the other file.

   ```
   $ echo B1 >b.txt
   $ git add b.txt
   $ git commit -m 'change B'
   ```

#### Rebase

```
$ git checkout -b rebased master
$ git rebase --keep-empty -i :/base
```

… choosing to `edit` the commit where `A` and `B` are added, and changing it so that only `B` is added (in a real scenario the reason might be that `A` is confidential):

```
$ git rm a.txt
$ git commit --amend
$ git rebase --continue
```

Naturally, the next commit where `A` is modified now gives a conflict:

```
error: could not apply 182aaa1... change A

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 182aaa1701ad100fc02a5d5500cacebdd317a24b... change A
```

… choosing to not add the modified version of `a.txt`:

```
$ git mergetool
Merging:
a.txt

Deleted merge conflict for 'a.txt':
  {local}: deleted
  {remote}: modified file
Use (m)odified or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort? d
```

The commit where `A` was modified is now empty:

```
$ git diff --cached
# nothing
```

… and finishing the rebase:

```
$ git rebase --continue
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/rebased.
```

#### Question

So now I have two versions of my history, with the difference that there is no trace of `A` in one of them. However, because I chose the `--keep-empty` option, I still expect an empty commit to exist in `rebased`, which would show me that `A` would have been modified, had it been there.

But apparently, this is not the case:

```
$ git log --oneline master
f893569 change B
182aaa1 change A
3340b71 add A and B
38cb5da some base commit to not run into the root corner case

$ git log --oneline rebased
73a2c05 change B
55f502b add A and B
38cb5da some base commit to not run into the root corner case
```

Is this not what `--keep-empty` is supposed to do, or does it not work
correctly?

---

Related: [Rebase on the root and keep empty commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529723/rebase-on-the-root-and-keep-empty-commits) is a very similar question, but it involves the `--root` corner case which I explicitly avoided here. And it has no answer, only some comments which suggest that what I'm showing here should work. Another difference is that in the other question the commit is empty in the first place, while here it only becomes empty after resolving a conflict.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's sort of a bug, due to something that is sort of a feature. :-)

When you run interactive rebase and it "pauses", in reality, it *finishes*, but leaves some files around to let a *new* `git rebase` realize that it's more of a continuation after all.  This is fine as far as it goes; you will need to run `git rebase --continue` later to start a new rebase and tell it: *You're not really new, go read the state and act like you're continuing the original rebase.*

And, let's look at an "interactive rebase".  In reality this is mostly a series of cherry-pick operations: the `pick` command literally instructs the old rebase shell script—which is being phased out now—to run `git cherry-pick`.

OK, no big deal so far.  But let's consider *why* an interactive rebase stops.  There are two reasons:

1. You marked a commit "edit".  It actually commits the cherry-pick, and stops to let you amend the commit or otherwise fuss with it.
2. Or, there was a problem—such as a merge conflict—that forced the stop.

In case (1), when you run `git rebase --continue`, Git should *not* make its own commit.

In case (2), when you run `git rebase --continue`, Git *should* make its own commit.  That is, it should unless—this is the feature part—you make your own commit first.  In that case, for case (2) Git should *not* make its own commit.

Git could, and perhaps should, record the reason-for-stoppage so as to tell these two cases apart ... but it doesn't.  Instead, it just looks at the state on `--continue`.

For a *non*-interactive rebase, Git knows that it only stops on conflicts, so it knows to try to make a commit, and complain if there is nothing to commit.  This is where the `--keep-empty` or `-k` flag is useful.  (Internally, the non-interactive case uses `git format-patch` and `git am` by default, although you can force it to use the interactive machinery with `--preserve-merges` for instance.  I mention this here as it's an *implementational reason* that Git has to know whether you're being "interactive": as so often happens, here Git lets the implementation dictate the behavior.  If Git didn't need this distinction, a `--continue` could just use the same code for interactive and non-interactive rebase, but Git *does* need the distinction, and hence doesn't use the same code.)

For an interactive rebase, though, Git *allows* you to make your own commit in case (2), just before running `git rebase --continue` (this is the Feature part).  If so, the `--continue` step should just move on to the next commit.  So `--continue` just checks whether there's something to commit now, rather than whether the earlier interactive rebase exited for case (1) vs case (2).  This simple implementation trick enables the feature, but also means that `--keep-empty` *cannot* work here: Git just doesn't know the difference.

The workaround is to do your own `git commit --allow-empty` after resolving your merge.  In other words, convert case (2) into a simulated case (1), using the "you may make your own commit" feature.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That also explains why Git actually didn't complain about an empty commit, which surprised me a little when not using `--keep-empty` in my inital attempt.

Comment: Did you mix up (1) and (2) in the first sentence of the second-to-last paragraph?

Comment: Um, don't think I did, case (2) is "stop due to merge conflict", and that's where you're allowed-but-not-required to commit after resolving the conflict.

Comment: The sentence is certainly correct, but I thought you wanted to make the distinction between interactive and non-interactive rebase (given the beginning of the sentence), and case (1) is where they differ. But OK, if the sentence is like you intended it, I just wanted to make sure it's no typo.

Answer (score 5):

> However, because I chose the `--keep-empty` option, I still expect an empty commit to exist in rebased, which would show me that A would have been modified, had it been there.
>
> But apparently, this is not the case:

Double-check that with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), considering "`git rebase --keep-empty`" still removed an empty commit if the other side contained an empty commit (due to the "`does an equivalent patch exist already?`" check), **which has been corrected**.

See [commit 3d94616](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d946165e1177905103a25aeb374e018c510e540), [commit 76ea235](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76ea235891c08e43226391cceaca8be056a1f803), [commit bb2ac4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb2ac4fcacaf5044b44e2acb918da33a4cca6af1) (20 Mar 2018) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d892bee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d892beef52a293b271538481dbc76014672ddf09), 25 Apr 2018)</sup>

> ### `rebase -i --keep-empty`: don't prune empty commits
>
> If there are empty commits on the left hand side of `$upstream...HEAD` then the empty commits on the right hand side that we want to keep are pruned by `--cherry-pick`.
>   Fix this by using `--cherry-mark` instead of `--cherry-pick` and keeping the commits that are empty or are not marked as cherry-picks.

And:

> ### `rebase --keep-empty`: always use interactive rebase

`rebase --merge` accepts `--keep-empty` but just ignores it, by using an
implicit interactive rebase the user still gets the rename detection
of a merge based rebase but with with `--keep-empty` support.

> If rebase `--keep-empty` without `--interactive` or `--merge` stops for the
>   user to resolve merge conflicts then '`git rebase --continue`' will
>   fail. This is because it uses a different code path that does not
>   create `$git_dir/rebase-apply`.
>   As `rebase --keep-empty` was implemented using `cherry-pick` it has never supported the am options and now that interactive rebases support `--signoff` there is no loss of functionality by using an implicit interactive rebase.

---

Note: this is part of a larger feature added to `git rebase` in Git 2.18:
See "[What exactly does Git's “`rebase --preserve-merges`” do (and why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309)".
With `git --rebase-merges` (which will ultimately replace the old `git --preserve-merges`), you now can rebase a whole topology of commit graph elsewhere.

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git rebase`" (again) learns to honor "`--no-keep-empty`", which lets the user to discard commits that are empty from the beginning (as opposed to the ones that become empty because of rebasing).

> The interactive rebase also marks commits that are `empty` in the `todo`.

See [commit 50ed761](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50ed76148a96d6cf37549c0492e6da1ff85b9bd0), [commit b9cbd29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9cbd2958f235614e9af687691c96bb001945f86), [commit 1b5735f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b5735f75c7fd5a46a86adce35d1ed0c6e00ee0f) (11 Apr 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c7d8f69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7d8f69da5443788950b823bd6b9b663e1e686a3), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9cbd2958f235614e9af687691c96bb001945f86): reinstate --no-keep-empty
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Bryan Turner</sup>
>   <sup>Reported-by: Sami Boukortt</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
>
> Commit [d48e5e21da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d48e5e21da980c6d439655a1292d0332b341c7d1) ("rebase (interactive-backend): make --keep-empty the default", 2020-02-15, Git v2.26.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c22bd9ff9d4a355d3546181698307a797fd2bd2) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f268890c2cd2f115424936bbee27f8269080e5e)) turned `--keep-empty` (for keeping commits which start empty) into the default.
>
> The logic underpinning that commit was:
>
> 1. '`git commit`' errors out on the creation of empty commits without an override flag
> 2. Once someone determines that the override is worthwhile, it's annoying and/or harmful to required them to take extra steps in order to keep such commits around (and to repeat such steps with every rebase).
>
> While the logic on which the decision was made is sound, the result was a bit of an overcorrection.
>
> Instead of jumping to having `--keep-empty` being the default, it jumped to making `--keep-empty` the only available behavior.
>
> There was a simple workaround, though, which was thought to be good enough at the time.
>
> People could still drop commits which started empty the same way the could drop any commits: by firing up an interactive rebase and picking out the commits they didn't want from the list.
>
> However, there are cases where external tools might create enough empty commits that picking all of them out is painful.
>
> As such, having a flag to automatically remove start-empty commits may be beneficial.
>
> Provide users a way to drop commits which start empty using a flag that existed for years: `--no-keep-empty`.
>
> Interpret `--keep-empty` as countermanding any previous `--no-keep-empty`, but otherwise leaving `--keep-empty` as the default.
>
> This might lead to some slight weirdness since commands like:
>
> ```
> git rebase --empty=drop --keep-empty
> git rebase --empty=keep --no-keep-empty
> ```
>
> look really weird despite making perfect sense (the first will drop commits which become empty, but keep commits that started empty; the second will keep commits which become empty, but drop commits which started empty).
>
> However, `--no-keep-empty` was named years ago and we are predominantly keeping it for backward compatibility; also we suspect it will only be used rarely since folks already have a simple way to drop commits they don't want with an interactive rebase.

Answer (score 0):

i also met this issue.

- 3328dbe - add hello world test code for jpa                                                                                     — Minghui Ma (HEAD) - (14 minutes ago)
- 3fd2d95 - init empty commit

when i use cmd " git rebase -i --root --keep-empty"
 there was no commit "3fd2d95 - init empty commit"

so i force insert one line "pick 3fd2d95 init empty commit" at the first line.